# How do I run multiple protocols at once?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to run `Wait`, `Begin`, and `Float` all at the same time where 
`Wait` is a timer, `Begin` sets up the bubbles and `Float` makes the bubbles rise

- V is for setting off the timer
- W is for making the bubbles rise
- X is for the spawn location
- Y is for slightly moving left/right
- Z is for the bubble being used

Code:

```
import turtle
import random
from random import randint
turtle.bgcolor("black")
turtle.setup(500,500)
Await = randint(1,4)/2
Bwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Await
Cwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Bwait
Dwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Cwait
Ewait = randint(1,4)/2 + Dwait
Fwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Ewait
Gwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Fwait
Hwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Gwait
Iwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Hwait
Jwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Iwait
Kwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Jwait
Lwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Kwait
Mwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Lwait
Nwait = randint(1,4)/2 + Mwait
Owait = randint(1,4)/2 + Nwait
A = turtle.Turtle()
B = turtle.Turtle()
C = turtle.Turtle()
D = turtle.Turtle()
E = turtle.Turtle()
F = turtle.Turtle()
G = turtle.Turtle()
H = turtle.Turtle()
I = turtle.Turtle()
J = turtle.Turtle()
K = turtle.Turtle()
L = turtle.Turtle()
M = turtle.Turtle()
N = turtle.Turtle()
O = turtle.Turtle()
A.shapesize(.5)
B.shapesize(.5)
C.shapesize(.5)
D.shapesize(.5)
E.shapesize(.5)
F.shapesize(.5)
G.shapesize(.5)
H.shapesize(.5)
I.shapesize(.5)
J.shapesize(.5)
K.shapesize(.5)
L.shapesize(.5)
M.shapesize(.5)
N.shapesize(.5)
O.shapesize(.5)
def Float(z):
    w = 1
    while w < 520:
        z.forward(1)
        z.left(90)
        y = randint(-1,1)
        z.forward(y)
        z.right(90)
        w = w + 1
def Begin(z):
    x = randint(-250,250)
    z.shape('circle')
    z.color('black')
    z.penup()
    z.right(90)
    z.forward(260)
    z.left(90)
    z.forward(x)
    z.left(90)
    z.color('red')
    z.speed(.5)
    Float(z)
def Wait(v):
    if v == Await:
        Begin(A)
        Wait(Await + .1)
    if v == Bwait:
        Begin(B)
        Wait(Bwait + .1)
    if v == Cwait:
        Begin(C)
        Wait(Cwait + .1)
    if v == Dwait:
        Begin(D)
        Wait(Dwait + .1)
    if v == Ewait:
        Begin(E)
        Wait(Ewait + .1)
    if v == Fwait:
        Begin(F)
        Wait(Fwait + .1)
    if v == Gwait:
        Begin(G)
        Wait(Gwait + .1)
    if v == Hwait:
        Begin(H)
        Wait(Hwait + .1)
    if v == Iwait:
        Begin(I)
        Wait(Iwait + .1)
    if v == Jwait:
        Begin(J)
        Wait(Jwait + .1)
    if v == Kwait:
        Begin(K)
        Wait(Kwait + .1)
    if v == Lwait:
        Begin(L)
        Wait(Lwait + .1)
    if v == Mwait:
        Begin(M)
        Wait(Mwait + .1)
    if v == Nwait:
        Begin(N)
        Wait(Nwait + .1)
    if v == Owait:
        Begin(O)
    v = v + .1
Wait(0)
```

Comment: It's not clear from your code exactly what you are trying to achieve here. Before we start trying to debug the code, can you explain at a higher level what the aim of the code is. What do you want to do/happen?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but any time you are tempted to have variables like this, you should be thinking "no, this is wrong, I need a data structure instead". This is a perfect job for an array, or possibly dict. And most times when you want to gather several pieces of related data, like turtle object and associated wait time, and also some related behaviour, like beginning, floating and waiting, you might consider a class to bind them together.

Comment: I'm trying to make a rising bubbles animation using a timer. It's for a science fair project

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing v by one every time the function *Wait()* is called **once**. It looks like you want it to loop? It's hard to understand. This makes the code actually run, but I don't know if that's what you want it to do.

```
def Wait(v):
    while True:
        if v == Await:
            Begin(A)
            Wait(Await + .1)
        if v == Bwait:
            Begin(B)
            Wait(Bwait + .1)
        if v == Cwait:
            Begin(C)
            Wait(Cwait + .1)
        if v == Dwait:
            Begin(D)
            Wait(Dwait + .1)
        if v == Ewait:
            Begin(E)
            Wait(Ewait + .1)
        if v == Fwait:
            Begin(F)
            Wait(Fwait + .1)
        if v == Gwait:
            Begin(G)
            Wait(Gwait + .1)
        if v == Hwait:
            Begin(H)
            Wait(Hwait + .1)
        if v == Iwait:
            Begin(I)
            Wait(Iwait + .1)
        if v == Jwait:
            Begin(J)
            Wait(Jwait + .1)
        if v == Kwait:
            Begin(K)
            Wait(Kwait + .1)
        if v == Lwait:
            Begin(L)
            Wait(Lwait + .1)
        if v == Mwait:
            Begin(M)
            Wait(Mwait + .1)
        if v == Nwait:
            Begin(N)
            Wait(Nwait + .1)
        if v == Owait:
            Begin(O)
        v = v + .1
```

Regardless of what you want it to do. Look into classes. You're creating a lot of repetitive data. Classes are like templates of data, that you can then use easily. I rewrote the code for you:

```
class Turtle:
    def __init__(self, wait, turtle):
        self.wait = wait
        self.turtle = turtle
        self.turtle.shapesize(.5)
        self.v = 0
    def Wait(self, time):
        if self.v == 2:
            return
        self.Begin()
        self.v += 1
        self.Wait(self.v)
    def Begin(self):
        x = randint(-250,250)
        self.turtle.shape('circle')
        self.turtle.color('black')
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.right(90)
        self.turtle.forward(260)
        self.turtle.left(90)
        self.turtle.forward(x)
        self.turtle.left(90)
        self.turtle.color('red')
        self.turtle.speed(.5)
        self.Float()
    def Float(self):
        w = 1
        while w < 520:
            self.turtle.forward(1)
            self.turtle.left(90)
            y = randint(-1,1)
            self.turtle.forward(y)
            self.turtle.right(90)
            w = w + 1



turtles = []
prev_wait = 0
for x in range(20): 
    wait = randint(1,4)/2 + prev_wait
    turtles.append(Turtle(wait, turtle.Turtle()))
    prev_wait = wait

for turtle in turtles:
    turtle.Wait(0)
```

Comment: I want the timer to loop and end when it spawns the last bubble. It needs to keep running while Begin runs. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

Below is an implementation of what I believe your code tries to do.  It's likely more complicated than you're prepared to take on at this point, but I hope it gives you ideas of how to rework your own code.  Particularly in the concept of a bubble prototype and cloning to avoid much redundant code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

BUBBLE_COUNT = 9
BUBBLE_DIAMETER = 10
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def bubbles_rise():
    for start_time, bubble in bubbles:
        if time > start_time and bubble.ycor() < HEIGHT/2 + BUBBLE_DIAMETER:
            bubble.forward(1)

            dx = randint(-1, 1)

            if dx != 0:
                bubble.setx(bubble.xcor() + dx)

    if any(bubble.ycor() < HEIGHT/2 + BUBBLE_DIAMETER for _, bubble in bubbles):
        screen.ontimer(bubbles_rise, 10)
    else:
        print("Finished rising!")

def bubbles_launch():
    global time

    for start_time, bubble in bubbles:
        if time >= start_time:
            bubble.showturtle()

    if any(start_time > time for start_time, _ in bubbles):
        time += 0.1
        screen.ontimer(bubbles_launch, 100)
    else:
        print("Finished launching!")

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor("black")

bubble_prototype = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
bubble_prototype.penup()
bubble_prototype.sety(-HEIGHT/2 - BUBBLE_DIAMETER)  # just out of sight
bubble_prototype.color('red')
bubble_prototype.shapesize(BUBBLE_DIAMETER / CURSOR_SIZE)
bubble_prototype.setheading(90)
bubble_prototype.speed('fastest')

bubbles = []

start_time = 0

for _ in range(BUBBLE_COUNT):
    start_time += randint(1, 4) / 2
    new_bubble = bubble_prototype.clone()
    new_bubble.setx(randint(BUBBLE_DIAMETER - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - BUBBLE_DIAMETER))  # just inside
    bubbles.append((start_time, new_bubble))

time = 0

bubbles_rise()
bubbles_launch()

screen.mainloop()
```